# What is the | operator doing in Java?

Tags: java, operators, bit, binary-operators

I read some Java code and came across the **|** operator.
Can anyone what the operator is doing in this context?

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            x[i] = hexBytes[i*4]   << 24
                 | hexBytes[i*4+1] << 16
                 | hexBytes[i*4+2] << 8
                 | hexBytes[i*4+3];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitwise `OR` (and `AND`) can be used for bit handling. `AND` allows you to extract a set of bits: `int lowest8bits = 0xFFFFF & 0xFF;`.

With `OR` you can insert bits. In the code above, 4 bytes are inserted to the same `int` by shifting them to the right position and `OR`ing them.

```
                           10010010 byte
                  10010010 00000000 << 8
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010110 The int we're building
00000000 00000000 10010010 00010110 End result in int after OR
```

Comment: @MarkusPfeifenberger speed is irrelevant. Do you understand what the code does now?

Comment: Not everything in detail. I have to go through the Docs and practice, do get a better understanding of how it works in Java

Comment: It's not about Java, it's basic bit handling which is not *that* common in Java code.

Comment: Thanks. The example you added described it very well.
Is there any useful situation where I can use it?

Comment: Probably not. It's for low level bit handling, so unless you're manually writing hash functions or things like that, you're probably not going to use it too often.

Answer (score 1):

Operators used are:

1. "<< (left shift)" : Binary Left Shift Operator. The left operands
   value is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right
   operand.

   2. ">> (right shift)" : Binary Right Shift Operator. The left operands value is moved right by the number of bits specified by the
      right operand.
   3. "| (bitwise or)" : Binary OR Operator copies a bit if it exists in either operand.

In your code:

```
hexBytes[i*4]   << 24
```

binary value of hexBytes[i*4] is left shifted by 24 bit. same with others and the result is OR by the bitwise | operator.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helps me to understand the Code